# Dust template unable to render page and display flash message on adding ,update,delete new items

Tags: node.js, dust.js

---

VError: Problem rendering dust template
   "C:\Projects\06_Bookstore\TekBooks\public\templates\manage\books\index.dust": 
    Path must be a string.
    Received Chunk {

- [the problem appears as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1xrA.png)
- [console page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TfdY.png)
- link to github page[Here is the code for the project](https://github.com/MrDataScientist/Nodejs-10-projects-examples/tree/master/06_Bookstore/TekBooks)

---

About Problem:
1.On add book Redirects to the page with above error on performing Add books.
2.it appears as runtime error on a webpage as well as console. No app crash or stopping server.
3.the add book operation successfully happens in the database. and displays the new book added on the webpage. But fails to redirect to "manage/books"(correct) page and display flash message.
4.only on refresh redirected to "manage/books"(correct) page. but still, flash mssg does not appear on refresh.
5.Which should instead automatically redirect to "manage/books" after posting add book form?
6. redirects to correct URL but unable to render the page.

Kindly please help me, developers, I am very new to node programming and indeed a beginner. In great need of help else, I will remain stuck. Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It is problem with the flash module. I had the same problem.

Delete req.flash and all will be good.

Bryan Traversy had a mistake when do it.